# Determining the Orbits/Orbit Space of $O(3)$ on Real 3 by 3 Traceless Symmetric Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-actions

Let $O(n)$ be the set of $3 \times 3$ orthogonal matrices, and $S$ be the set of traceless real symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrices.

Now  $O(n)$ will act on $S$ by conjugation.
Note that by the spectral theorem $ \forall A \in S$ in the orbit of $A$ there is a diagonal matrix $D=diag(\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\lambda_3)$ with $\lambda_1\le\lambda_2 \le\lambda_3 $.

Determine the all the orbits of the action & the orbit space of the action.

**What I've done:**

Since all elements of $S$ are diagonlizable that the orbit of any element should be the orbit of its' diagonalized form because $\forall A \in S,   \exists P \in O(3)$ st  $PAP^t=D $ with $D$ a diagonal matrix and moreover for any other  $Q\in O(3)$ we get $QDQ^t=QPAP^tQ^t=(QP)A(QP)^t=RAR^t$.

And so would that imply the orbit space is just the set of traceless diagonal matrices as $tr(QDQ^t)=tr(DQ^tQ)=tr(Q)$ (cyclic property of trace) and $Q\in S$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly. Note that if you permute the entries of a diagonal matrix along the diagonal, the resulting diagonal matrix belongs to the same orbit. So, the orbit space is smaller than what you've suggested.